# InputStream.available() and reading file compeletly notes from oracle

Tags: java, android, file-io, inputstream, bufferedreader

according to :

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the
>   total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never
>   correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer
>   intended to hold all data in this stream.

from:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29

and this note

```
In particular, code of the form

int n = in.available();
byte buf = new byte[n];
in.read(buf); 

is not guaranteed to read all of the remaining bytes from the given input stream.
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/troubleshooting.html

dose it mean that using `below function` cause not to read file completely?

```
/**
 * Reads a file from /raw/res/ and returns it as a byte array
 * @param res Resources instance for Mosembro
 * @param resourceId ID of resource (ex: R.raw.resource_name)
 * @return byte[] if successful, null otherwise
 */
public static byte[] readRawByteArray(Resources res, int resourceId)
{
    InputStream is = null;
    byte[] raw = new byte[] {};
    try {
        is = res.openRawResource(resourceId);
        raw = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(raw);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        raw = null;
    }
    finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return raw;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

available() returns the number of bytes that can be read *without blocking.* There is no necessary correlation between that number, which can be zero, and the total length of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does not necessarily read all. Like `RandomAccessFile.read(byte[])` as opposed to `RandomAccessFile.readFully(byte[])`. Furthermore the code actually physically reads 0 bytes.

It probably reads only the first block, if it were a slow device like a file system.

> ***The principle:***
>   The file is being read by the underlying system software, normally
>   buffered, so you have a couple of blocks already in memory, and
>   sometimes already reading further. The software reads asynchrone
>   blocks, and **blocks** if trying to read more than the system has
>   already read.

So in general one has in the software a read loop of a block, and regularly at a read the read operation blocks till the physical read sufficiently buffers.

To hope for a non-blocking you would need to do:

```
InputStream is = res.openRawResource(resourceId);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for (;;) {
    // Read bytes until no longer available:
    for (;;) {
        int n = is.available();
        if (n == 0) {
            break;
        }
        byte[] part = new byte[n];
        int nread = is.read(part);
        assert nread == n;
        baos.write(part, 0, nread);
    }
    // Still a probably blocking read:
    byte[] part = new byte[128];
    int nread = is.read(part);
    if (nread <= 0) {
        break; // End of file
    }
    baos.write(part, 0, nread);
}
return baos.toByteArray();
```

Now, before you copy that code, **simply do a blocking read loop** immediately. I cannot see an advantage of using `available()` unless you can do something with partial data while reading the rest.

Comment: +1 for your answer but `the code actually physically reads 0 bytes.` i do not think so

Comment: and also i do not see any connection of my question and reading blocking or non-blocking.

Comment: One thing I did not state: `available()` returns the number of bytes that can be read without blocking (= are buffered already). So `available()` can yield 0 at any moment, i.e. at the very beginning. My argument: one can do blocking reads, without penalty. Only when doing more work like reading N files in a loop `available()` might be worthwhile. **I hhope someone coming along, wants to formulate the case a bit more clear.**

Comment: @mmlooloo The connection is that hat is the definition of what available() returns. It is a misuse of it to use it as the total length of the stream.